# Python not running basic textbook code from IDLE

Tags: python-3.x

Using IDLE in python 3.5.2 on OSX

I typed the following code in IDLE:

```
def hello(name): 
  return("Hello " + name)

hello('Bob')
```

I clicked on Run module, the shell appeared to run the code however it did not output "Hello Bob" as expected. My whitespace is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You `hello` method is returning `"Hello " + name` but when you call it `hello('Bob')`, you either need to store the result in some variable or simply print it.

If you just want to print returned value of your `hello` method, change `hello('Bob')` to `print(hello('Bob'))`

```
def hello(name): 
  return("Hello " + name)

print(hello('Bob'))
```

**Output**

`Hello Bob`